# Выбор Linux

Tags: linux

Друзья, подскажите, хочу установить на ноут Linux и не знаю, какой выбрать. Что мне нужно: сервер для веб-разработки (apach) и простенький компилятор, так как я только начал изучать язык с.

Comment: Может, все-таки Linux?

Comment: извините, подправил

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов, этим требованиям удовлетворит практически любой дистрибутив, это тот случай, когда можно свободно выбирать по личным предпочтениям и внешнему виду.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для новичков наилучший вариант - какой-то вариант Ubuntu. Чистую убунту можно попробовать, но мне не нравится ни графическая оболочка Unity, ни Gnome3. Сам пользуюсь Xubuntu - та же убунту, но с оболочкой Xfce. Если ноутбук достаточно мощный, можно попробовать Kubuntu - с KDE.

Почему убунту? Достаточно простая, много программ в репозитории, большое количество пользователей и как следствие - в сети можно найти решение практически всех проблем, особенно если дружите с английским языком. 
Apache, PHP, gcc - все это есть и работает на ура.

Comment: @skegg спасибо за подробности, вас не затруднит скинуть ссылку на скачивание  Xubuntu, а то на linux.com я нашёл только Emmabuntüs

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/

Comment: Есть подозрение, что для ноутбука и для заявленных целей хватит Lubuntu - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lubuntu

Comment: Не так давно решил перейти с Ubuntu на менее требовательный дистрибутив (нетбук). Ставил Xubuntu, выплыл баг с выходом из спящего режима. Об этом можно погуглить. Куча способов исправить - ниодин не подошел. Поставил Lubuntu - пока что всё устраивает, интерфейс правда из нулевых.

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов, @A1essandro xfce сыроватая, на мой взгляд. Посоветую ubuntu с cinnamon.

Comment: @A1essandro: "интерфейс правда из нулевых" А ваша Галя-то балувана! :)

@Гошка Тарасов: Что касается компилятора, то рекомендую Tiny C Compiler - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler

Comment: @VadimTukaev это вариант для совсем бедных машин, после того, как polkit в очередной раз навернулся при апдейте, я туда не вернусь.

Answer (score 3):

Я бы порекомендовал Linux.Mint.
Вот, к примеру, ссылка http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4857807, можно создать загрузочную флэшку, посмотреть, если понравиться, с этой флэшки и установить.

Comment: линуксы нужно качать с оф.сайтов: http://www.linuxmint.com/download.php

Comment: @deivan, более того, там есть возможность скачать через торрент.

Answer (score 3):

Тоже порекомендую **Linux Mint**.
Та же Ubuntu, но доведённая до ума. Меньше Убунтовских глюков (программисты доработали) и практически все те же программы и советы из Интернета можно использовать.

То есть в основе Линукс Минт использована Убунту - издание переработанное и дополненное. 17-я версия Минта мне понравилась (соответствует 14-й Убунте, Trusty).

Основные версии у Минта - это **Mate** и **Cinnamon**. Пользоваться удобно и тем, и тем. 
Mate менее требовательно к железу. В смысле подойдёт к более слабым компьютерам. 
Синамон *"красивше"* и навороченней. Хотя внешний вид, умеючи, со временем можно настроить как угодно, хоть под Винду ХР.

Скачать можно, например, отсюда:
http://линуксминт.рф/catalog/1005

Comment: есть еще KDE edition, которая мне очень по нраву

Comment: :-) Из неё и пишу

Comment: Просто рекомендовать начинающему Linux Mint KDE или Kubuntu я не решился, потому что там есть своя специфика. 

А вот Мате или Синнамон используют в основном те же программы, что и Убунту с Юнити.

Answer (score 2):

Однозначно, это Linux Mint!

Answer (score 2):

Если новичок, то linux mint.